# Python plot bar chart and percentage line chart on same graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot one or more lines on the same chart as a bar chart to show a few different metrics. I heard I should use ax.twinx() for this, but I either get an error saying x and y must have the same first dimension, or a different error reading 0L based on the two things I tried. Here is my code;

```
    x = df4['Date']
    y = df4['Rate']
    ax = df4[['Date','Qty']].set_index('Date') \
                            .plot(kind='bar',
                                  stacked=False,
                                  color = 'dodgerblue',
                                  figsize=(13,4),
                                  legend=True)
    ax.set_xlabel(r"$\rm \bf{Date}$",
                  fontsize=18, 
                  rotation = 0)
    ax.set_ylabel(r'$\cal \bf{Qty}$ ',fontsize=18, rotation = 90)

    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    ax2.plot(x, y, color = 'green', linestyle = '--', linewidth= 2.0)
```

Note; df4 is a grouped pandas dataframe. Not sure how relevant that is but just in case.

Comment: could you please post a sample data set in __text/CSV__ format so we could test solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()


df4[['Date','Qty']].set_index('Date') \
                   .plot(kind='bar',
                         ax=ax,
                         color = 'dodgerblue',
                         figsize=(13,4),
                         legend=False)

patches, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(patches, labels, loc='upper left')

ax.set_xlabel(r"$\rm \bf{Date}$", fontsize=18, rotation=0)
ax.set_ylabel(r'$\cal \bf{Qty}$ ',fontsize=18, rotation=90)

ax2.plot(range(len(df4)), df4['Rate'], 'green', label='Rate',
         linestyle = '--', linewidth=2.0)

patches, labels = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax2.legend(patches, labels, loc='upper right')
```

NOTE: if you want a tested solution, please provide a sample data

Comment: This actually worked perfectly, thank you! I am relatively new to the site so thank you for the tip as well.

Comment: @JacobDavis, glad i could be helpful :)

Comment: Of all solutions I read here about this topic, only this one worked. A bit complicated (I wish you could comment on how it is working actually), but definitely worth it!